# Python Tkinter scale widget but not cover full window height, why?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scale

I'm doing an assignment but need your advise positioning scale in tkinter, I do not have any success, trying multiple options, perhaps you could give me an idea:

The scale should cover full length of my window, but only gets centred
Why ?, I will need to add more scales in the near future without change screen dimensions.

Thanks

```
import Tkinter as tk

from random import randint

from Tkinter import *
class MyApplication(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

    Frame.__init__(self, master)    
        self.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.canvas=tk.Canvas(master, width=400,   
        height=400,background='white')    
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
        label = Label(self, text='Count')
        label.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=(N,S,E,W))
        self.sc1 = Scale(self, variable=1, from_=100, to=1)
        self.sc1.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=1,sticky=(N,S,E,W))
        self.sc1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>")

        button = Button(root,text='Start')
        button1 = Button(root,text='Stop')
        button2 = Button(root,text='Clear')
        button.grid(row=400,sticky=(W))
        button1.grid(row=400,sticky=(N))
        button2.grid(row=400,sticky=(E))

# Main 
root = Tk()
app = MyApplication(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is there a reason you're creating a frame object, but the canvas and some of the buttons are being created as  a child of the root window? That's very unusual, and makes your code hard to understand. What's the point of the frame class if it doesn't encapsulate all of the widgets?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating a control panel, is there a better way of doing ?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. You made a specific design decision to create a subclass of Frame, which typically serves as a container for other widgets. However, this container creates widgets both in it, and in the root which is a highly unusual thing to do. Is there a specific reason you're doing it that way? Normally the only widgets created by the subclass of a frame are children of the frame, not children of the root.